# Override an event's param array?

Tags: plugin-development, events

I'm having problems setting up an event. It gets triggered and I can access the event's params array, but I can't override the value like I can with Craft's default events.

MyPlugin_myServiceService.php

```
public function setTest()
{
    $test = true;

    $event = new Event($this, array(
        'test' => $test
    ));

    $this->onAfterSetTest($event);

    return $test;
}

public function onAfterSetTest(Event $event)
{
    $this->raiseEvent('onAfterSetTest', $event);
}
```

MyOtherPluginPlugin.php

```
craft()->on('myPlugin_myService.afterSetTest', function(Event $event)
{  
    $event->params['test'] = false;
});
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but 
`craft()->myPlugin_myService->setTest()` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lindsey D's comment to my first answer, I had a closer look at [custom hooks](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#hooks) and found out that this is indeed the better solution to do this.

MyPlugin_myServiceService.php

```
public function setTest()
{
    $test = true;

    craft()->plugins->call('modifyTest', array(&$test));  

    return $test;
}
```

MyOtherPluginPlugin.php

```
public function modifyTest(&$test)
{
    $test = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it doesn't updated the variables passed to the event directly (referenced) and you have to access the value from the `$event` object.

```
public function setTest()
{
    // ...

    $test = $event->params['test']

    return $test;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you may need a custom **hook**, instead of an event. Generally speaking, events aren't supposed to modify the data which triggered it.

Comment: Totally right, a hook is really the better solution to do this. Thank you!